# str.contains using the na=Nan Flag

Tags: python, pandas

I still can't wrap my head around what the na flag does exactly in the `df.str.contains(string na=True/False)`.

The documentation says: `Fill value for missing values`.

But what does it replace those missing values with?

Also what happens if you set it to True and and what happens if you set it to False.

Can someone please provide me with some examples of both scenarios.

Comment: you could generate some data and play with the options to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `df.str.contains()` returns :

> A Series or Index of boolean values indicating whether the given pattern is contained within the string of each element of the Series or Index.

So you will get a series of boolean values (True/False) for each element in your df series based on whether or not the substring is present in the element.

Here is an example :

```
sr = pd.Series(['Mouse', 'dog', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN])
sr.str.contains('og', na=False)


0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

So here I was checking if substring `og` is present in the elements of my series. It returned a series of boolean values for each element in input series.

Also, notice I had a `Nan` value in my original series.

Now what should happen incase the element is `Nan`?
What should we consider as the output of `.str.contain()` in this case ?

Ans. - Here is where the flag `na` comes into play. We can specify what to consider as the boolean outcome for elements having `Nan` value.

In the above example I set the flag `na=False` which will return False incase element in the series is `Nan`.

Hope this helps:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 2):

First str.contains function only works on pandas series.
Whatever value you give for na, it will fill that value in the output.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'v1':['dog','cat','cog',np.nan],'v2':['23','zip',np.nan,'4']})

df['v1'].str.contains('g',na=False)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: v1, dtype: bool

df['v1'].str.contains('g',na=True)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: v1, dtype: bool

df['v1'].str.contains('g',na=2)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3        2
Name: v1, dtype: object
```

As you can see, it fills the last na value with the given value.